# jenkins embeddable build status icon not shown in Confluence

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have tried the above and each time I set theanonymous user with view access, it completely breaks my active directory link and I have to mess around replacing the config.xml from a backup.

Anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: Also just clicked on the I tried the 'Image' URL option and pasted that in a confluence page, the icon didnt show but when I clicked on the URL it took me straight to the the Build Status !!...  any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of write a comment.

Comment: .. and show the HTML code as displayed in Confluence. Also check your Browser's console in its Developer Tools.

Comment: so using the attach image function in confluence and pointed that to the HTML image URL and that seems to work fine